# slice numpy/pandas array based on a None value in one of the array/columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have the following code where im trying to slice/transform a data array into multiple Dataframes, then concat those dataframes together

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

arr=[['id',          'aaa',   'bbb',   None,    'ccc',   None, None],
     ['period',      'd',     'd',     None,    'd',     None, None],
     ['date',        'price', 'price', 'volume','price','volume', 'mktcap'],
     ['01/03/2001',  103.1,   103.2,   10000,   103.4,   20000, 1000000],
     ['01/04/2001',  104.1,   104.2,   11000,   104.4,   30000, 1000000],
     ['01/05/2001',  105.1,   105.2,   12000,   105.4,   40000, 1000000],
      ]

data=np.array(arr)

all_ts =[]
for col in range(1,data.shape[1]):
   id = data[0][col]
   per = data[1][col]
   if id is None:
      continue

   #from the 3rd row, take the date column and the current col and produce a dataframe
   ts_data = data[2:,[0, col]]
   cols = ts_data[:1,][0]         
   ts_data = pd.DataFrame(ts_data[1:], columns=cols)
   ts_data = ts_data[cols].dropna()
   ts_data['id'] = id
   ts_data['period'] = per
   all_ts.append(ts_data)

df = pd.concat(all_ts) 
df
```

The code above will only generate datframes with columns with columns:
`id, period, date, price` because when it encounters a None, i continue (as i cant figure out how to grab the following 'None' columns as yet).

What i would like to end up with are 3 dataframes:

1. The 1st with columns: `id, period, date, price`
2. The 2nd with columns: `id, period, date, price, volume`
3. The 3rd with columns: `id, period, date, price, volume, mktcap`

So basically, from row 3, i want to take the first column (date column) plus the 'field' columns and produce a dataframe - the catch im struggling with though is that multiple fields should be taken together if the subsequent fields have None above them (i.e. in the period or id columns).

**Edit/Update:**
i was able to do this with the following tweak...but it doesnt feel very pythonic/numpyic. note the addition of another variable named `select_cols`, which keeps getting appended to when a None is encountered.   Im thinking numpy must present a better way of doing this...just not sure what that may be.

```
all_ts =[]
select_cols = [0]
for col in range(1,data.shape[1]):
   id = data[0][col]
   per = data[1][col]
   select_cols += [col]
   if id is None:
      continue

   #from the 3rd row, take the date column and the current col and produce a dataframe
   ts_data = data[2:, select_cols]
   cols = ts_data[:1,][0]         
   ts_data = pd.DataFrame(ts_data[1:], columns=cols)
   ts_data = ts_data[cols].dropna()
   ts_data['id'] = id
   ts_data['period'] = per
   all_ts.append(ts_data)
   select_cols=[0]

df = pd.concat(all_ts) 
df
```

Comment: Does making `arr` an array (object dtype?) do anything for you.  numpy is best for numeric data, soso for strings, and little better, if not worse,, than lists for objects like None.

Comment: It's easier I think to slice using numpy. I need slice and stack the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, I did come up with this way of doing this using functional pandas programming. Is it more pythonic? Hard to say...

```py
data = np.array(arr)
df = (pd.DataFrame(data[3:,1:],
                   # build column index from the first three rows, forward filled to remove None values
                   columns=pd.DataFrame(data[:3,1:]).ffill(axis=1).values.tolist(),
                   # row index is the first value in each row of actual data
                   index=pd.Index(data[3:,0], name=data[2,0])
                  )
    # melt the column index
    .melt(ignore_index=False)
    # and rename the columns back to their original names
    .rename(columns={ f'variable_{i}' : arr[0] for i, arr in enumerate(data[:2]) })
    .reset_index()
    # now pivot the values based on the data columns
    .pivot(index=['date'] + list(data[:2,0]), columns='variable_2', values='value')
    .reset_index()
    # get rid of the unnecessary column index name
    .rename_axis('', axis=1)
    # and sort on id
    .sort_values('id')
)
```

Output for your sample data:

```
         date   id period   mktcap  price volume
0  01/03/2001  aaa      d      NaN  103.1    NaN
3  01/04/2001  aaa      d      NaN  104.1    NaN
6  01/05/2001  aaa      d      NaN  105.1    NaN
1  01/03/2001  bbb      d      NaN  103.2  10000
4  01/04/2001  bbb      d      NaN  104.2  11000
7  01/05/2001  bbb      d      NaN  105.2  12000
2  01/03/2001  ccc      d  1000000  103.4  20000
5  01/04/2001  ccc      d  1000000  104.4  30000
8  01/05/2001  ccc      d  1000000  105.4  40000
```